# Deleting cabinet files

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a script to delete cabinet files in virtual servers. For some reason, the code that I've created ends up not deleting any cabinet files and instead tries to delete the entire WINDOWS Directory, and I have no idea why this is occurring. Was curious if anyone might have any ideas on what the issue may be, since I can't find anything:

```
$dir = "\\$server" + '\C$\windows'

$cabinetArray = @()
foreach ($item in get-childitem -path $dir){
    if ($item.name -like "*.cab"){
        $cabinetArray = $cabinetArray + $item
        }
    }

for ($i = 0; $i -le $cabinetArray.length; $i++){
    $removal = $dir + "\" + $cabinetArray[$i]
    remove-item $removal -force -recurse 
    }
```

I did some testing and it seems that for some reason my array that I'm trying to use to gather all the cabinet files isn't even getting filled for some reason. I'm not sure if there's a specific way to only gather the .cab files since right now whenever I run this on my test server it tries deleting everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if deleting all the cab files in that folder is a good idea or not, but I'll answer your question.  You're doing a lot of math and building your own collection of objects when PoweShell will do it all for you.  Try something like this:

```
$dir = "\\" + $server + '\C$\windows'
$cabinetFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter "*.cab" -Recurse
$cabinetFiles | %{
    Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName -Force
}
```

Or, as a one liner:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path ("\\" + $server + '\C$\windows') -Filter "*.cab" -Recurse | %{Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName -Force}
```

Comment: Thanks Chris! Didn't know there was a way to do this in one line, but that makes things really helpful. Quick question will this one liner work for pretty much anything that you want to get? Just wondering for future references.

Comment: It should, yeah.  Also - before you run it, add -WhatIf after the remove-item cmdlet to make sure it's only deleting what you want it to.  Then remove it so the files will actually be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Use the pipeline, here's a simplified version of your code (remove -WhatIf do delete the files). The code gets all *.cab files from the windows directory of the remote box (recursively), makes sure that only file objects passes on and then deletes them.

```
Get-ChildItem "\\$server\admin$" -Filter *.cab -Recurse | 
Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer} | 
Remove-Item -Force -WhatIf
```

Answer (score 1):

> For some reason, the code that I've created ends up not deleting any cabinet files and instead tries to delete the entire WINDOWS Directory, and I have no idea why this is occurring.

It is occurring because your for loop is being entered, and that is happening because $cabinetArray's length is zero. Once the for loop is entered, the $removal variable is assigned the value of $dir plus a trailing backslash. You are then calling remove-item on the windows directory.